# Unity: Como navegar entre dois pontos em uma esfera?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estou precisando criar um sistema de navegação entre dois pontos em uma esfera, o problema é que como o NavMesh da Unity não funciona com objetos esféricos tenho que calcular e posicionar manualmente o objeto até o seu destino.

Criei uma lógica que talvez não funcione, onde o calculo entre a distância do objeto e o destino mais a distância até o centro me daria a posição do objeto, e reduzindo alguma porcentagem da distância até o player eu teria uma nova posição para mover o objeto, porém não consegui ir além, pois não consigo converter esse cálculo para o Vector3 por inúmeros problemas que encontrei.

Qual maneira correta de fazer isto? considerando que não posso utilizar o Navmesh, e que a navegação do objeto até o player tem que ser gradual.

Segue abaixo uma imagem que representa a lógica (Talvez sem sentido, rs) que imaginei que pudesse funcionar, e um script que iniciei.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class NavMeshController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Settings")]
    public GameObject toPoint; // Ponto de destino
    public PlanetController sphere;

    private Renderer renderer;
    private float radious;
    private float center;

    void Start ()
    {
        renderer = sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        radious = getRadious();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        // transform.Translate(toPoint.transform.position * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }

    float distanceToPoint()
    {
        return Vector3.Distance(transform.position, toPoint.transform.position);
    }

    float distanceToCenter()
    {
        Vector3 center = renderer.bounds.center;
        return Vector3.Distance(transform.position, renderer.bounds.center);
    }

    float getRadious()
    {
        SphereCollider sphereCollider = sphere.GetComponent<SphereCollider>();
        return Mathf.Max(sphereCollider.transform.lossyScale.x, sphereCollider.transform.lossyScale.x, sphereCollider.transform.lossyScale.x) * sphereCollider.radius;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pense por outro lado: caminhar em uma esfera pode ser o mesmo que "rodar" sobre o eixo central desta. Simplesmente você pode por o pivô do personagem no centro, "subir" ele até que esteja fora da esfera, e mexer nos ângulos apenas. Se precisar fazer coisas usando distâncias, etc, ou _pathing_, aí já vai precisar fazer cálculos geodésicos.

Comment: Outro detalhe, se seu objeto consegue seguir o player, basta deixar a esfera com Rigidbody, assim o objeto é obrigado a andar sobre a esfera e não através dela! (Isto caso eu tenha entendido sua pergunta)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução é usar coordenadas esféricas. Este sistema de coordenadas te posiciona em uma esfera utilizando os parâmetros raio, angulo phi e angulo theta. Enquanto o sistema cartesiano, utilizado pelo unity, te posiciona em formato cubico com parâmetros x, y e z.

Faça o seguinte:

1) Converta a posição do player e do objeto para coordenadas esféricas, através das seguintes funções:

[image: cartesiana para esferica]

2) Incremente ou decremente os angulos theta e phi de modo a aproximar o objeto do player.

3) Converta de volta para coordenadas cartesianas (x,y,z) e mova o objeto para as novas coordenadas, utilizando as seguintes funções:

[image: x]

[image: y]

[image: z]

r é o raio da esfera. Em geral ele é um parâmetro do sistema esférico de coordenadas, mas se você for permanecer na superfície sempre, você pode fixá-lo.

x, y e z são as coordenadas do sistema cartesiano.

phi e theta são as coordenadas do sistema esférico que você utilizará.

Fonte: 
http://fma.if.usp.br/~fleming/diffeo/node4.html
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_esf%C3%A9rico_de_coordenadas

Comment: Convém também referir que r é positivo, theta está compreendido entre 0 e 2*PI e phi entre 0 e PI.